# What does the Permission error mean when trying to read in Excel files using the xlrd module?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am just trying to figure out how to read in a data set from Excel using the xlrd module. When I run my code I am getting the permission error [errno 13]. I'm not sure what the error means or why I am getting it.
Here is my code I am using:

```
import xlrd
loc = ("path to the file I'm trying to read in")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0)
print(sheet.nrows)
```

and this is the output I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "GaitOptMain.py", line 46,
>   in 
>       wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)   File "C:\Users\mleef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py",
>   line 116, in open_workbook
>       with open(filename, "rb") as f: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: [path that I used in the code]

Comment: Do you have access to the file? Is it password protected? Can you open with Excel without any issue/prompts?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the files with no passwords or prompts.

Comment: Is it possible you have the document open in excel? If I'm not mistaken excel blocks workbooks you have opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to figure it out. I think the problem is that I was trying to read in a directory and not an actual file. the path I was using ended at the folder and not the file.

```
    loc = ("C:/Users/mleef/Desktop/python text/practice_data.xlsx")
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet.cell_value(0,0)
    print(sheet.nrows)
```

output:
1429 (number if rows in the data set)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have the file already open, you will see this error

Comment: How do you ensure that the file is already closed in the previous execution before reading it?